# SQL - Percentage of total in addition to other summations

Tags: sql

I'm using `group by` and `sum()` to provide the total loan amount for each state. There's a lot going on in the From and Where clause but just to generalize I wrote the fake code below to get a sense of what I'm trying to do. In addition to summing the loans for each state (which I have working) I'd like to add the percentage of each state relative to the entire population. Problem is, I can't figure out how to generate the denominator to arrive at the percentage of total.

```
Select State, 
       Sum(LoanAmount), 

<<<How do I add the percentage of total for each state here. 
I'm not sure how to get the denominator so I can do the math.
I need to be able to sum all the  loans by basically ignoring
the group by that's in place >>>

From LoanTable
group by State
```

Comment: What is the dbms you are using?

Comment: Please provide the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result for that sample data.

Comment: Provide your table definition and the queries you do, not some "there's a lot going on in the From and Where clause but just to generalize I wrote the fake code below"

Comment: Before asking a question, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery and a join. So something like...

```
WITH sumQuery AS (
 SELECT State, SUM(LoanAmount) AS Total
 FROM LoanTable 
 GROUP BY State
)
SELECT t1.state, t2.Total, (t1.LoanAmount*100)/t2.Total AS 
Percentage
FROM LoanTable t1
FULL OUTER JOIN sumQuery AS t2 ON t1.state = t2.state
```

Here is an example of how it works: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/85fb6/22)

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions:

```
Select State,
       Sum(LoanAmount) * 1.0 / sum(sum(LoanAmount)) over () as ratio
From LoanTable
group by State;
```